Enclosing a variable string of values with a bracket within a larger string all contained within a single cell
I have cells which contain a ! followed by a Alpha Numeric String which varies in length.
I want to change the ! to NOT( which is relatively easy, the part I am struggling with is the closing bracket after the Alpha Numeric String
ie
!AlphaNumericString becomes NOT(AlphaNumericString)
Cell examples before change,
AND(!BI,OR(Z1,Z2,Z102,Z103,Z104,Z306))
!L1M23 OR (NP001 AND !CA);
Z200 AND !VP100;
!N001L010D132
I want those cells to become,
AND(NOT(BI),OR(Z1,Z2,Z102,Z103,Z104,Z306))
NOT(L1M23) OR (NP001 AND NOT(CA));
Z200 AND NOT(VP100);
NOT(N001L010D132)
The Exclamation is always followed by 1 character, then it would be a series of alpha numeric characters and that Exclamation string will always end with one of the following
Space
)
;
,
Or it could end with the last character in the cell,
As per the above examples
Hope that makes sense.
I would prefer a Macro so it is backward compatible from EXCEL 365 back to 2010, but if there is simple formula, awesome.
Thanks
mbart67

You can try this UDF (User Defined Function) and use it on the sheet as =myReplace(A1) where cell A1 is housing your original string.
The function is;
Function myReplace(myRange As Range) As String
    Dim regExp As Object
    
    Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    regExp.IgnoreCase = True
    regExp.Global = True
    regExp.Pattern = "!([A-Z0-9]*)"
    
    myReplace = regExp.Replace(myRange.Text, "NOT($1)")

    Set regExp = Nothing
End Function



And it works in Excel 2010 per the OP's tags.

@nkalvi, then he can use Google Sheets which is cross browser and operating system.... =REGEXREPLACE(A1,"!([A-Z0-9]+)","NOT($1)")

A non-regex solution:
Function exclamToNot(s As String) As String

    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim c As String
    Dim t As String
    
    Const terminators As String = ");, "
    
    
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
    
    c = Mid(s, i, 1)
    
 ' Check for exclamation mark
 
    If c = "!" Then
        found = True
        t = t & "not("
        
    ' Check for end of string controlled by exclamation mark
    
    Else
        If found And InStr(terminators, c) > 0 Then
            found = False
            t = t & ")" & c
            
        ' Normal character
        
        Else
            t = t & c
        End If
    End If
            
    Next i
    
    ' Add final bracket if we have reached end of string after exclamation mark
    
    If found Then t = t & ")"
    
    exclamToNot = t

End Function


I was wondering if you could use the exact same logic in a sheet formula. This seems to work OK:
=LET(
    c, MID(s, i, 1),
    terminators, ";,) ",
    IF(
        i > LEN(s),
        IF(found, ")", ""),
        IF(
            c = "!",
            "NOT(" & Repex(s, TRUE, i + 1),
            IF(
                AND(found, ISNUMBER(FIND(c, terminators))),
                ")" & c & Repex(s, FALSE, i + 1),
                c & Repex(s, found, i + 1)
            )
        )
    )
)

called as
=repex(A1,false,1)

and saved as a lambda so it looks like this in the name manager:


Recursive version is very nice! Almost handles !(OR(A-B, !(C-D)), E) => NOT((OR(A-B), NOT((C-D))), E)

Thank you! I shall drive myself mad trying to get the nested case working now.

Tom, thanks for the assist, the function (exclamToNot) you provided works like a charm.
I also got someone to do it in Regex, so simple when you know how that works,  That solution provided below.

Thanks for the inspiration @TomSharpe, though my attempt is crude, I couldn't help attempting :)

The LAMBDA(s,found,i, ) is essential for the LET function to work, but than it works. I like the approach.

Nice & helpful as it includes not only a VBA, but also a sheet formula approach - 'vtd +:) - fyi Posted another tricky non-regex approach you might be interested in. @TomSharpe


but if there is simple formula, awesome

Not really, but in Office 365 we can combine formulas to get the result you want:
=MAP(A1:A2, 
 LAMBDA(a,
     REDUCE(a,SEQUENCE(LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a,"!",))),
     LAMBDA(r,_,
LET(x,MID(r,FIND("!",r),LEN(r)),
    y,TOROW(HSTACK(FIND({" ","(",";",","},x),LEN(x)+1),2),
IFERROR(
        SUBSTITUTE(
                   REPLACE(r,
                           MIN(y+FIND("!",r)-1),
                           ,
                           ")"),
                   "!",
                   "NOT(",
                   1),
        r))))))

Basically it checks for the number of times ! is found in the initial text string to set the number of iterations for reduce, which I declared as _ since it's used for the iterations, but nowhere called within the function anymore.
The initial text string itself is declared as r .
Iteration
We search for the first found ! in string r and find the closest  ,),;,,-character or the end of the string after the first found ! (whichever comes first), add a ) behind it and replace that first count ! with NOT(.
If the above errors, keep r, if not the replaced/substituted r becomes the new r and repeat the iteration _ times.
I used MAP to loop the formula over various cells at once, but you can replace the MAP/LAMBDA-part with LET(a,A1,REDUCE(.. to make it work on a single cell if required.
If you're on Beta channel you could use:
=REGEXREPLACE(A1:A2,"!(\w+)","NOT($1)")

There may be an easier way using REGEXREPLACE but that's still in beta channel.

Thanks, yes that works,  I would never have gotten that as I still do not understand all those formula, yet but I can see what it is trying to do.
Is it possible to get that written as a MACRO Function so I do not have to type all that out when it is needed?
Thanks Heaps, works a treat  :)

Record as macro and write away as value?

I also added the REGEXREPLACE option, in case you have access to it (or it may become available in the near future).

Attempt with recursion, trying to handle nesting:
Define exclaim_not in Name Manager:
=LAMBDA(str, IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("!", str)), LET(delims, {"("," ",",",";",")"}, left_, LEFT(str, FIND("!", str) - 1), right_, exclaim_not(RIGHT(str, LEN(str) - LEN(left_) - 1)), symbol_len, MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(delims, right_), LEN(right_) + 1)) - 1, symbol, LEFT(right_, symbol_len), after_symbol, RIGHT(right_, LEN(right_) - LEN(symbol)), left_ & "NOT" & IF(AND(LEFT(after_symbol) = "(", RIGHT(after_symbol) = ")"), IF(LEN(symbol), "(" & symbol & after_symbol & ")", after_symbol), "(" & symbol & ")" & after_symbol)), str))

Formatted:
=LAMBDA(str,
    IF(
        ISNUMBER(FIND("!", str)),
        LET(
            delims, {"(", " ", ",", ";",")"},
            left_, LEFT(str, FIND("!", str) - 1),
            right_, exclaim_not(RIGHT(str, LEN(str) - LEN(left_) - 1)),
            symbol_len, MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(delims, right_), LEN(right_) + 1)) - 1,
            symbol, LEFT(right_, symbol_len),
            after_symbol, RIGHT(right_, LEN(right_) - LEN(symbol)),
            left_ & "NOT" &
                IF(
                    AND(LEFT(after_symbol) = "(", RIGHT(after_symbol) = ")"),
                    IF(LEN(symbol), "(" & symbol & after_symbol & ")", after_symbol),
                    "(" & symbol & ")" & after_symbol
                )
        ),
        str
    )
)



This is really excellent, should have more attention. Maybe I will try and reverse-engineer it or something like it into VBA (maybe).  Also it shows how stackoverflow ought to work.

Your kind feedback is very valuable - thank you! I used VB decades ago, haven't used VBA much. Prefer to use JS and Swift these days :)

Alternative to regex using a negative Like pattern
Instead of checking and adding each character one by one to a total string, this approach

splits each code line via the relevant "!"-separator into tokens,
identifies the starting alpha-numeric variable string varStr of each token via helper function getVarStr(),
executes a simple replacement via function Enclose() and
joins the modified tokens to the final result.

Example call
Sub EncloseExclam()
'Purp: Replace "!" and following variable alpha-num string part with surrounding elements
    With Sheet1.Range("A2:A5")    ' << redefine as needed
        Dim data: data = .Value2
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
             data(i, 1) = enclose(data(i, 1)) ' << Function enclose()
        Next i
        .Offset(, 1) = data
    End With
End Sub

Function enclose()
Function enclose(ByVal s As String) As String
'Purp.: Execute "!"-replacement by given prefix+"(" ENCL and closing bracket ENCL2
'0) Define constants
Const REPLACECHAR = "!", ENCL = "NOT(", ENCL2 = ")"
'1) Split code into tokens
    Dim tokens:  tokens = Split(s, REPLACECHAR)
'2) Loop through all "!"-split tokens
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(tokens)  ' i=1, as very first index i=0 can't contain "!"
        'Identify variable alphanum string
        Dim varStr As String: varStr = getVarStr(tokens(i))
        tokens(i) = Replace(tokens(i), varStr, ENCL & varStr & ENCL2, Count:=1)
    Next i
'3) Join tokens as function result
    enclose = Join(tokens, "")
End Function

Note that the Replace function includes a Count:=1 argument which is necessary here to garantee that only a first string occurrence will be replaced (as each token 1..n split by the "!" separator comprises only one term to be replaced). //edited 2024-08-23//
Helper function getVarStr()
Uses a negative character check via a negative Like operator pattern, e.g. "[!A-Z0-9]" (note the exclamation mark ! before A-Z0-9, i.e. identifying the first non-alphanum character).
As a further benefit one can pass an optional argument UCaseOnly:=False to allow also lower case chars within the variable string.
Function getVarStr(ByVal s As String, Optional UCaseOnly As Boolean = True) As String
'Purp:  get starting alphanumeric string part
    Dim Pattern As String
    Pattern = IIf(UCaseOnly, "[!A-Z0-9]", "[!A-Za-z0-9]")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) Like Pattern Then
            s = Left(s, i - 1): Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    getVarStr = s
End Function


This got me what I needed, thank you for the assistance :)
Function ConvertString(s As String) As String
    With CreateObject(Class:="VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "!([A-Z0-9]{1,})"
        .Global = True
        ConvertString = .Replace(s, "NOT($1)")
    End With
End Function


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

ok, but rather close to @Haluk 's solution :-;

@T.M.; almost 99.9%  .... :)
